# How set HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name for Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

**Background:**

I'm testing a function within an ASP.NET 4.0 (Web Forms not MVC) and I'm using Unit Testing built into Visual Studio 2010. I've created a separate test project and creating a test class for each class in the web project.

**Question:**

I've run into an issue with one of the functions that uses HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name as part of the logic. How do set that value in the Unit testing project class or method so that I can test that function?

**Update:**

What I was hoping for was that there was additional attribute I could set above my test method. Currently I have:

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("ASP.NET")]
[AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\DEV\\ProjectName\\ClientWeb", "/")]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:9018/")]
public void GetLoginTest()
{
  // test code
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit Testing Web Services - HttpContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028056/unit-testing-web-services-httpcontext)

Comment: RE: Attributes, HttpContext.Current isn't compatible with unit testing. You need and abstraction of some type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask the wrong question. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is a dependency you should encapsulate before you can unit test your code. If encapsulated (probably behind an Interface) you can replace the abstraction with your test data / object.

Comment: It’s harder to find an entry link on that theme as I thought. If you google for Dependency Injection + HttpContext you get much stuff, but most of it is related to special dependency injection  containers. Here is a link with poor man’s dependency injection giving you the general idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251636/asp-net-mvc-and-ioc-chaining-injection

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `Principal` by implementing `IPrincipal`, within that you'd need to define a custom `Identity` using the `IIdentity` interface, inside which you'd return your value for the `Name` property.

You could then set `HttpContext.Current.User` to your custom Principal object.